# Non-interactive GoogleVis charts

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

Is it possible for googleVis Package from R to generate Images as oppose to interactive charts? To create a GoogleVis Chart in R:

```
library(googleVis)
M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year")
plot(M)
```

This initiates a browser and then it will plot an interative chart. Is there a way such that I can create a non-interactive image and plot it in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hacks I found that could potentially be able to convert gvis charts to images:

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

https://gist.github.com/battlehorse/1333906

Answer (score 2):

What I have done is a complete hack, but it works. I view the HTML for the googleVis object generated and extract the svg. I save the svg as a file and open it in an image editor that can open and convert svg files.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how you do this? I am trying to save my googleVis plots as a SVG for further formatting.

Comment: I start with "plot()" of the googleVis output, which opens it in my web browser (chrome). I then view the source and drill down to the SVG (which will be between <svg></svg> tags). I copy this and paste it, saving it as flat text. I can then open the text with Inkscape, which recognizes it as SVG. From there, I can export it as multiple file types, such as metafile or something that can be opened with GIMP.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need to use googleVis for this. If you create your plot in ggplot2, the ggthemes add-on package has theme_gdocs(), and associated colour palettes that will let you style your chart exactly like a Google Chart.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only way to do this is to make the interactive plot, and take a screenshot. The object returned by googleVis is a Flash application embedded in html, I think you probably cannot expect it to give a static plot!